# Indent a theorem using `thmtools`and `cleveref`

Tags: indentation, cleveref, thmtools

I use 'mathtools`package to define my theorem styles and`cleveref` to be able to re-enumerate it. But this package does my old code

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{remark}{%
  \patchcmd\@thm{\trivlist}{\list{}{\leftmargin\parindent\rightmargin
\parindent}}{}{}
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endremark{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}
}
```

useless.

Is there a way to get indentation of the body text of the theorem ''remark''?
Here is my `mwe`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove=\topsep,
spacebelow=\topsep,
headfont=\small\itshape,
bodyfont=\normalfont\small,
headpunct={.---},
postheadspace=1em,
headformat=\NAME\space\NUMBER,
headindent=\parindent
%   qed=$\blacktriangleleft$
]{remark}
\declaretheorem[style=remark]{remark}


\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
\lipsum[1}
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cleveref` the patching should be different, because it redefines `\@thm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep,
  spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\small\itshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\small,
  headpunct={.---},
  postheadspace=1em,
  headformat=\NAME\space\NUMBER,
  %headindent=\parindent,
  %qed=$\blacktriangleleft$,
]{remark}
\declaretheorem[style=remark,name=\translate{Remark}]{remark}

\makeatletter
\preto\remark{%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmnoarg
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin\parindent\rightmargin\parindent}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd\cref@thmoptarg
    {\trivlist}
    {\list{}{\leftmargin\parindent\rightmargin\parindent}}
    {}{}%
  \patchcmd\thmt@original@endremark{\endtrivlist}{\endlist}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{remark}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{remark}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly on `LaTeX` but not in `XeLaTeX`. Why? What changes are needed?

Comment: @Dog_69 I see no problem with XeLaTeX. Do you get an error or what?

Comment: Yes, it also works. Suddenly it had not effect. But it is working again. Thanks.